# What can be done to avoid non linear snapping when cutting large tiles by the score and snap method?

Tags: tile

These are porcelain tiles
I am referring to cracks like in the picture below
They seem to be caused by the fact that the vertical force used to snap/crack the  tile is applied at the opposite end and it is probably uneven or diminished at the other end of the tile

[image]

Comment: Diamond blade saw and water cut really well.

Comment: a better tool and a bigger hammer is always the answer but I was asking about this specific method and not for wet cutting

Comment: After scoring, how are you snapping it? Over an edge the full length of the tile?

Comment: (Timed out on my edit) if you’re using a score and snap tool, with the v-shaped foot that breaks the tile, you could try two things: a second scoring pass to score more deeply, and slide the movable part to snap from the middle of the tile.

Comment: I am using Qep Slim line 24. You cant try to snap on the middle as the blade will touch the tile first ...only at the far end of the cut the blade/scoring disk cleard the tile and then that foot thar is used to snap the tails can e used. They say one gently scoring pass only

Comment: Scoring a shallow grove on the front surface then scoring the other side, then breaking it by tapping and bending.

Comment: Add something hard to fit between the lever legs and the tile to raise the wheel but land the feet, so that you can snap in the middle of the tile rather than at the end. You could try two pieces of tile. Whether this works depends on the dimensions of the lever/fulcrum.

Comment: On the bright side, it's leaving extra material to be removed and not veering into the piece you want to keep, ruining it.

Answer (score 2):

Ceramic tiles approved for flooring and porcelain tiles are much harder than the ceramic wall tile variants, and they require deep and continuous scoring in order to provide a straight snap cut.

When the snap cut curves away from the scoring line (as in your picture) it means that the scoring was not deep enough especially at and around the tile edge where the scoring starts (because it is opposite from where the tile is pressed to snap).

When scoring, apply more pressure and roll slowly.

Make sure the cutting wheel scores both ends around the tile edge, that is, the glazed top but also some of the ceramic side. After scoring once by pushing the lever and wheel forward, roll the wheel back and ride the tile edge a few times to make sure it is clearly scored. Do this for both tile edges.

Then snap with a rapid and firm movement of the lever.

Should this still fail, use a a tile nipper (or a wet saw) to score both ends deeper.

Comment: I have a cheap (crap) score/snap tool and I find it hard to score the ends of the score line properly in only one direction.  I have to score in both directions, and each end gets scored properly only when moving towards its edge.  But moving towards the snap foot is awkward because it gets in the way so it has to be propped up.   I think this answer is good advice, but to generalize: "Make sure it's thoroughly scored".